# How can I create and initialize a dictionary/JSON equivalent data structure in JSP?

Tags: python, java, json, dictionary, jsp

I have the following sample data:

```
{
    "2022-37" : "2022-09-17 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-38" : "2022-09-24 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-39" : "2022-10-01 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-40" : "2022-10-08 00:00:00.0"
}
```

If this was python, I would create a dictionary like this,

```
week_to_date_dict = {
    "2022-37" : "2022-09-17 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-38" : "2022-09-24 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-39" : "2022-10-01 00:00:00.0",
    "2022-40" : "2022-10-08 00:00:00.0"
}
```

and access the data like this:

```
print(week_to_date_dict["2022-28"])
```

How can I achieve the same thing in a JSP file?

I did come across Hashmap but wasn't able to figure out how to initialize the data as above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialze a HashMap and - only in a JSP - use it the same way:

```java
var week_to_date_dict = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    put("2022-37", "2022-09-17 00:00:00.0");
    put("2022-38", "2022-09-24 00:00:00.0");
    put("2022-39", "2022-10-01 00:00:00.0");
    put("2022-40", "2022-10-08 00:00:00.0");
  }
};
```

```
<%= week_to_date_dict["2022-37"] %>
```